# Using the Present Progressive when describing a situation

Tags: tenses, present-progressive

I've noticed that use, and I like to learn more about the theory behind it. In that sense, why to choose this tense over the Simple Present.

For example:

> When you are **walking** around Denver and you're **thinking**, well, this is a nice area, this is really such a vital city...
>
> Similarly, if a word is **ending** in z, it will likely need to be changed
>   to c in order to smooth the pronunciation as in...

Comment: Using or not using the progressive construction is determined by the context of the story that's being told. These aren't even complete sentences; there's no context at all. How can anyone generalize about the appropriate use of random sentence fragments?

Comment: Here is another example, this time, in the passive voice:   "Using or not using the progressive construction is determined by the context of the story **that's being told.**"

Answer (score 3):

You use the progressive when you **think about** the situation as having a beginning and an end. For example, one person might say, "I live in Toronto" because they don't think about ever leaving Toronto. Another person, pehaps an international student studying at the U of T might say "I'm living in Toronto" because the person intends to leave after graduating. Again, it's not about the facts of the situation, since all situations have beginnings and ends. The speaker uses the progressive to tell the listener how the speaker is thinking about the situation.